# python 'int' object is not iterable. Please

Tags: python, loops, integer, syntax-error, iterable

Code:

```
liste10=[1,[2,3],[4,5,6,7]]
for i in liste10:
    for x in i:
        print(i)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[110], line 3
      1 liste10=[1,[2,3],[4,5,6,7]]
      2 for i in liste10:
----> 3     for x in i:
      4         print(x)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I was expecting to get [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].
I have no idea why I got such a result. I would be very happy if you could help me solve this problem.
s

Comment: I think you meant your input to be this `[[1],[2,3],[4,5,6,7]]`, the first element was not a list

Comment: The first item of `liste10` is the integer `1`, not a list, so you can't iterate on it. You might want a list containing a single item: `liste10 = [[1], .....]`

Answer (score 0):

You can either make `liste10` a list of lists as mentioned in comments, i. e. `[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]` so that your code works as expected, or check type of each object in `liste10` and act accordingly:

```
liste10 = [1, [2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]

for obj in liste10:
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for x in obj:
            print(x)
    elif isinstance(obj, int):
        print(obj)
    else:
        print("Unknown type!")
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```